# Compare Values Across Two Dataframes R

Tags: r, kable, kableextra, flextable, officer

I am building a crime report in `R` and am comparing two separate dataframes, one from the current year and one from the previous year. The data structure is the same in both. Is there a way to color the values in a flextable based on the crimes that were committed the previous year? So, for example, if the month of January 2020 had more homicides than January 2019 then color that value red. If the month of January 2020 had less burglaries than January 2019 then color that value green, and so on for every month of the year and for every crime. Here is a sample of the data:

```
df2019 <- data.frame(crime = c("assault", "homicide", "burglary"),
                 Jan = c(5, 2, 7),
                 Feb = c(2, 4, 0),
                 Mar = c(1, 2, 1))

df2020 <- data.frame(crime = c("assault", "homicide", "burglary"),
                 Jan = c(1, 2, 5),
                 Feb = c(1, 3, 0),
                 Mar = c(2, 2, 1))
```

My desired output is the to have the `df2020` values colored based on the `df2019` values (I have included a picture below). I would then like to include the table in a Powerpoint using the `Officer` package.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas? I have been exploring options in `kable`, `kableExtra`, and `flextable` but can't find any solutions that work across dataframes. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)

df2019 <- data.frame(crime = c("assault", "homicide", "burglary"),
                     Jan = c(5, 2, 7),
                     Feb = c(2, 4, 0),
                     Mar = c(1, 2, 1))

df2020 <- data.frame(crime = c("assault", "homicide", "burglary"),
                     Jan = c(1, 2, 5),
                     Feb = c(1, 3, 0),
                     Mar = c(2, 2, 1))

colors <- unlist(df2020[-1] - df2019[-1]) %>% 
  cut(breaks = c(-Inf, -.1, 0.1, Inf),
      labels = c("green", "transparent", "red")) %>% 
  as.character()

flextable(df2020) %>% 
  bg(j = ~ . -crime, bg = colors) %>% 
  theme_vanilla() %>% 
  autofit() %>% save_as_pptx(path = "test.pptx")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, David! I copy and pasted your solution and although it compiles the data nicely in a flextable, the colors don't work on my end. Any idea why?

Comment: no. Did you open the file with PowerPoint (no LibreOffice, or other rich text editor)?

Comment: Yes I opened it with powerpoint. The flextable is the same as yours only without the colors. I copy and pasted your solution so I wonder why thats happening

Comment: It looks like the reason the colors weren't showing up was the `theme_vanilla()` line of code. When I take that out it runs perfectly! Thank you so much, David!

Comment: I changed theme_vanilla, I may have changed from white background to transparent background, with a recent version, you should have no problem